# Empacotar strings usando struct

Tags: python, python-3.x, struct

Estou fazendo um exercício básico usando o módulo `struct`, e me deparei com um problema: Para empacotar uma `string`, devemos informar no método `struct.pack()` o número de caracteres que ela possui, certo? Mas e se essa `string` for informada pelo usuário? Nesse caso, não sei quantos caracteres ela vai ter, então como posso empacotá-la?

Comment: Não sei ao certo como você está usando o `struct`, mas para ver o tamanho de uma string você poder usar o built-in `len()`.
len('abc') == 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Veja bem, como você cria uma string em C? A não ser que você declare e inicialize ao mesmo tempo, é necessário que você informe o tamanho da string. Certo?

Logo, você também deve fazer o mesmo quando for empacotar uma string com struct, pois, afinal, o módulo struct faz conversões de bytes em Python para structs em C e vice-versa. Aliás, se não me engano, não há como declarar uma string sem tamanho como membro de uma struct em C.

A limitação do tamanho faz mais sentido se você pensar que, posteriormente, alguém vai precisar desempacotar essa struct, e, portanto, ela deverá saber o seu tamanho, pois, caso o contrário, poderá fazer uma leitura errada misturando bytes de um dado com os de outro dado.

Agora, sobre o seu problema, se de fato você não consegue limitar a entrada do usuário (algo que deveria ser feito, por segurança), você poderia fazer algo do gênero:

```
str_ = input()

bytes = str_.encode()
tamanho = len(bytes) + 1

formatacao = "{}s".format(tamanho)
pacote = struct.pack(formatacao, s)
```

Lembre-se que o tamanho de uma string pode ser diferente da sua representação em bytes:

```
>>> len("ç")
1
>>> len("ç".encode())
2
```

Além disso, adicione 1 ao tamanho obtido, para a string poder ser finalizada adequadamente com um `\0` (lembra de strings em C?).

Se você conseguir persistir a string de formatação, poderá desempacotar sem problemas os seus dados.

No entanto, uma melhor abordagem, tendo em vista que esse pacote pode ser lido em um outro programa, é você empacotar a string junto com tamanho dela em bytes:

```
formatacao = "i{}s".format(tamanho)
pacote = struct.pack(formatacao, tamanho, bytes)
```

Assim, a pessoa que for ler sua struct, saberá que o primeiro valor é um inteiro que dirá quantos bytes para frente correspondem a string que fora armazenada antes. A ideia é ter um cabeçalho com as informações necessárias para ler os dados e um corpo com os dados a serem lidos.

Fez sentido? Segue um exemplo completo:

**Empacotando**

```
>>> entrada = input()
sabão
>>> bytes = entrada.encode()
>>> tamanho = len(bytes) + 1
>>> formatacao = "i{}s".format(tamanho)
>>> pacote = struct.pack(formatacao, tamanho, bytes)
>>> pacote
b'\x07\x00\x00\x00sab\xc3\xa3o\x00'
```

**Desempacotando (com persistência da string de formatação)**

```
>>> tamanho, bytes = struct.unpack(formatacao, pacote)
>>> str_ = bytes.decode().strip('\0')
```

**Desempacotando (sem persistência da string de formatação)**

Primeiro, calculamos quantos bytes tem um inteiro, para podermos medir quantos bytes serão consumidos do nosso pacote:

```
>>> fim_int = struct.calcsize('i')
>>> tamanho_str = struct.unpack('i', pacote[:fim_int])
>>> tamanho_str = tamanho_str[0]  # unpack sempre retorna uma tupla, por isso o [0]
```

Depois, determinamos o tamanho da string com o primeiro dado pegado e calculamos os bytes que serão consumidos:

```
>>> formatacao = '{}s'.format(tamanho_str)
>>> inicio_str = fim_int
>>> fim_str = inicio_str + tamanho_str
```

Por fim, pegamos e tratamos a string:

```
>>> bytes = struct.unpack(formatacao, pacote[inicio_str:fim_str])
>>> str_ = bytes[0].decode().strip('\0')
```

Óbvio que esse exemplo tem algumas coisas esdrúxulas na questão idiomática do Python, mas tentei deixar o mais didático possível.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta! Entendi como se faz, mas restou uma dúvida: Você disse pra eu limitar a entrada do usuário (eu realmente não tinha pensado nisso), então vamos supor que eu limite a entrada em 10 caracteres e o usuário entre com 4 caracteres.
Isso vai dar algum problema na hora de empacotar/desempacotar?

Comment: Ah, outra coisa... Não estou conseguindo empacotar... Do jeito que você disse, eu só vou conseguir empacotar o número de caracteres, não estou conseguindo incluir a string no processo...

Comment: Não terá problema, tendo em vista que o resto será preenchido com `\0`, que é um caractere nulo. No entanto, quando você desempacotar e converter para string novamente, o tamanho dela será 10 em vez de 4, cabendo a ti alguma manipulação (ex. `strip('\0')`). Quanto ao outro  comentário, testei o código e tudo está ok, vou colocar um exemplo completo em breve.

Comment: Agora sim, com esse exemplo eu entendi (demorou um pouco, pois ainda sou novo no assunto e não sou muito familiarizado com o método `format`, sempre uso o `%`) mas deu certo, consegui empacotar todos os dados que eu queria no programa. Valeu!